# Frame over any size of image using php script + with imagemagick without command line

Tags: php, imagemagick

I have been stucked at some point where client needs to change the frame image over the product image. Means if image size is 200 * 400 then image frame will apply on the product image and if the product image is 400*200 then also same frame will be apply over the product image without any manual information(dynamically). I think it is possible using the imagemagick and for that I have found this url (http://www.fmwconcepts.com/imagemagick/picframe/index.php) but it is using command line But I want it without command line.

I am making something like the given page :- url: http://fineartamerica.com/products/conversations-laura-sue-canvas-print.html

Hope I have explained my problem well. Please help me out.
Thanks for your support in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i had a similar requirement following code worked for me

```
    $over = new Imagick($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] .'ks/new.png'); // load frame
    $pic = new Imagick($_FILES['pic']['tmp_name']); // load image
    $pic->resizeImage(1299,1722,Imagick::FILTER_LANCZOS,1); // resize your image to the size of your frame
    $pic->setImageFormat ("png"); //  set formate of final image
    $pic->compositeImage($over, Imagick::COMPOSITE_DEFAULT, (((($pic->getImageWidth()) - ($over->getImageWidth())))/2), (((($pic->getImageHeight()) - ($over->getImageHeight())))/2));
    $name=rand(1,10000000000);
    file_put_contents ("pictures/$name.png", $pic);
    $pic->destroy();
```

Answer (score 1):

Look at http://php.net/manual/en/function.getimagesize.php, no imagemagick needed

But to use external url, you should enable url_allow_fopen = true in you php ini (not sure if run time works)

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [`Imagick::frameImage()`](http://php.net/manual/en/imagick.frameimage.php) function.

```
$image->frameImage("#aabbcc", 20, 20, 5, 5);
```

would add a 20px blue frame around your image with 5px bevel.

Comment: Well, that's not possible with the current version of the extension, because there's no picFrame wrapper. But you can run `imagick -picframe` with [`exec`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php)...