# How to make tiled image frame without using exec function?

Tags: php, image-processing, imagemagick, gd, imagick

Original image:
[image: Original image]
Here what i need:
[image: Here what i need]
It should be created from this small tile:
[image: It should be created from this small tile]

A lot of people suggest to use ImageMagick solution (it using php exec function) - http://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=21867:

```
convert frame_template.gif \
-tile blackthin_top.gif -draw 'color 1,0 floodfill' -rotate 90 \
-tile blackthin_btm.gif -draw 'color 1,0 floodfill' -rotate 90 \
-tile blackthin_top.gif -draw 'color 1,0 floodfill' -rotate 90 \
-tile blackthin_btm.gif -draw 'color 1,0 floodfill' -rotate 90 \
-gravity center thumbnail.gif -composite frame_filled.gif
```

or

PICFrame solution (it using php exec function) - http://www.fmwconcepts.com/imagemagick/picframe/index.php:

```
picframe [-f frameid] [-m mattesize] [-c mattecolor] [-b bordersize] [-s shade] [-a adjust] [-o opacity ] [-d distance] infile outfile
```

PHP imagick has great ability to create color borders with:

```
$imagick = new \Imagick('image.jpg');
$imagick->scaleImage(300, 300, false);

// Create frame placeholder
$imagick->frameimage( 'red','30','30', 30, 0);

// Flood fill with color
$imagick->floodFillPaintImage('green', 10, '#6e0000',0, 0,false
);

header("Content-Type: image/jpg");
echo $imagick->getImageBlob();
```

But PHP imagick can't use your own image tile to create frame, only solid colors. Here is very related question - [How to flood fill the frame with a pattern image using imagick php class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33490101/how-to-flood-fill-the-frame-with-a-pattern-image-using-imagick-php-class)

Another good solution from - https://stackoverflow.com/a/28778953/2337706 but it creates image from big PNG frames and you should know correct image size.

I know that i can create it with php GD - http://php.net/manual/en/ref.image.php but i don't know correct way how implement it this way.

Comment: What is wrong with using PHP exec()? It makes it really easy to use a pre-existing solution and not have to invent it all over again

Comment: @fmw42 yes you are right, it's easy to use and convinient, but a lot of clients using shared hosting which don't provide access to php exec() or i am not right?

Comment: I do not do much with Imagick and have not tried this, but http://us3.php.net/manual/en/imagick.textureimage.php is the function that will tile an image. You should be able to use that to achieve your desired results.

Comment: I think you will need to ask your hosting provide if they allow PHP exec(). I have used it on Godaddy just fine.

Comment: You should be able to convert one of the tiled frames examples at http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/thumbnails/#frame_edge easily to Imagick.

Comment: @fmw42 Imagick::textureImage repeats tile over all image, it may be usefull, but not that i wanted. you are right as solution could be to ask hosting provider for php exec() or i could continue to discover how to implement that with php GD

Comment: You can tile the image over a narrow strip for the image and use that for the top. Then rotate it 90, 180 and 270, saving each for the frame sides. Then append all side images with the main image in the center.  The first example at the link I provided above does that in command line ImageMagick though he uses transpose. But you can do it with rotates. Or you can composite all the images over an appropriate sized blank background that is large enough to hold the image and frame images. You should be able to figure out how to convert each step into Imagick.

Comment: @fmw42 yes that's good tactic, but there could be problems with 45 degree edges. i would be happy if you can provide working imagick code. the best solution that works with php exec - http://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=21867#p90157

Comment: Sorry again I do not know Imagick. If you do not want edges at the corners to show from the frame tiling, then you need to use one of the examples further down on the link page I listed above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In ImageMagick, you could just do something simple like this:

```
convert a1Wit.jpg -mattecolor black -frame 10x10+3+3 -gravity west -chop 3x0 -bordercolor gold -border 3 frame_result.jpg
```

[image]

These commands should be easy enough to translate into Imagick.  See https://www.php.net/manual/en/imagick.frameimage.php and https://www.php.net/manual/en/imagick.chopimage.php and https://www.php.net/manual/en/imagick.borderimage.php

Or simply:

```
convert a1Wit.jpg -bordercolor black -border 7 -bordercolor "gray(35%)" -border 3 -bordercolor "#D0A456" -border 3 frame_result2.jpg
```

[image]

Or

```
convert a1Wit.jpg -mattecolor "gray(30%)" -frame 13x13+5+5 -gravity northwest -shave 5x5 -bordercolor "#D0A456" -border 3 frame_result3.jpg
```

[image]

Or

```
convert a1Wit.jpg -mattecolor "gray(30%)" -frame 13x13+5+5 -gravity northwest -bordercolor "#D0A456" -border 3 frame_result4.jpg
```

[image]

Adjust the color thicknesses as desired